# How to use Oracle indexed field in a query

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have a large Oracle table with an indexed date_time field: "DISCONNECT_DATE"

When I use the following where clause my query runs quickly:

```
DISCONNECT_DATE > TO_DATE('01-DEC-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND 
DISCONNECT_DATE < TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

When I use the following where clause my query runs (very) slowly:

```
extract(month from disconnect_date) = '12' and 
extract(year from disconnect_date) = '2016'
```

They are both more or less equivalent in their intentions.  Why does the former work and the later not? (I don't think I have this problem in SQL SERVER)

(I am using PL SQL Developer to write the query)

Comment: I guess Oracle can not automatically convert from your second option to the first option, so it full scans.  It would need a special case for this optimisation. PS. They are not equivalent unless you change > to >=

Comment: I am confused. Are you saying that in SQL Server both versions run very quickly? I don't know anything about SQL Server, but I would find that very surprising. (Unless you already have function-based indexes in SQL Server, like Gordon shows in his Answer.)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the use of indexes.  In the first, all the functions are on the "constant" side, not on the "column" side.  So, Oracle can readily see that an index can be applied.

The logic that does indexing, though, doesn't understand `extract()`, so the index doesn't get used.  If you want to use that construct, you can create an index on function calls:

```
create index idx_t_ddyear_ddmonth on t(extract(month from disconnect_date), extract(year from disconnect_date));
```

Note:  `extract()` returns a number not a string, so you should get rid of the single quotes.  Mixing data types can also confuse the optimizer.

Comment: What do you mean by "constant" side vs. "column" side.  Do you have an example where being on one side or the other of the equals makes a difference to Oracle?  I'd always assumed it made no difference.

Comment: @WW - not sides as in left vs. right; you can swap the terms over so the "column" reference is on the right-hand of the operator (changing the operator too to keep the logic the same if needed). This is referring to data coming from a column, directly or with manipulation (such as a function call, which is the issue here), being compared with a non-column-based expression. Whichever side each is on. [Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF00214), noting the second bullet point, and the section about the rules governing implicit data type conversions:.

Comment: @WW - Please pay close attention to what Gordon said in the last paragraph (about properly matching the data types of your expressions). He is 100% right - I am willing to bet more efficiency is lost (globally across all queries that run on all databases in the world) due to negligence regarding data types, than due to using functions around column values (like `extract()` in your example). Bonus++ to Gordon for taking the time to make that point!